# Using Intel Compiler SVML `__m128 _mm_sincos_ps ()` Effectively

Tags: optimization, vectorization, simd, avx, icc

I have a simple loop:

```
for (ii = 0; ii < numRows * numCols; ii++)
    {
        mCOmega[ii] = cosf(paramOmega * mI[ii]);
        mSOmega[ii] = sinf(paramOmega * mI[ii]);
    }

}
```

Which I want to optimize using Intel Compiler + SVML by using `__m128 _mm_sincos_ps ()`.

I'm struggling with the efficient way to load the data and store it from the output of `__m128 _mm_sincos_ps ()`.

What would be the most efficient way to write this loop with `__m128 _mm_sincos_ps ()`?

Comment: Any reason you cannot use auto-vectorization? Based on a [quick try](https://godbolt.org/z/vu1EVu) with Compiler Explorer (Godbolt), that seems to work just fine, as the generated code invokes the vector function `__svml_sincosf8_e9`.

Comment: It is part of a longer thing the Auto Vectorization won't optimize well. So I would like to write it manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following compiles on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Rxa234) without any problems:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mathimf.h>
#include <immintrin.h>

void test (const float * restrict mI, 
           float * restrict mCOmega,
           float * restrict mSOmega,
           float paramOmega,
           int numRows,
           int numCols)
{   
    __m128 x, sin_x, cos_x;
    int ii;
    for (ii = 0; ii < numRows * numCols; ii = ii + 4)
    {   x = _mm_loadu_ps((float*)&mI[ii]);
        x = _mm_mul_ps(x, _mm_set1_ps(paramOmega));
        sin_x = _mm_sincos_ps(&cos_x, x);
        _mm_storeu_ps((float*)&mCOmega[ii], cos_x);
        _mm_storeu_ps((float*)&mSOmega[ii], sin_x);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you pass `&mCOmega[ii]` directly as the output operand, like `_mm_sincos_ps(&mCOmega[ii], x)`?  Or does it require an aligned output operand?  (It might use `movups`; Intel's compiler likes to use `movups`).  If it doesn't inline, that saves a copy.

Comment: @PeterCordes, Is there a way to write the whole loop with `__m128` pointers? Something similar to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/178554/7723 (See `ptrOutputImageSse`).

Comment: @Royi: yeah, if you want.  That doesn't change anything about alignment requirements for `_mm_sincos_ps`, though: it's a library function, not inlined (unless I'm mistaken about how SVML works).  Anyway, FP load/store intrinsics take `float*`, not `__m128*`.  The AVX512 ones take `void*` so you could avoid casts there.

Comment: @PeterCordes : The intel manual says: " `*p_cos`: points to vector of cosine results (pointer must be aligned on 16 bytes, or declared as __m128* instead)". 
Anyway, it wouldn't make a difference: Functions `test1` and `test2` [compile to the same instructions](https://godbolt.org/z/av2-b3).

The values of `sin` and `cos` are apparently returned in `xmm0` and `xmm1`, 
which is more efficient than passing the results through the stack.

The Intel compiler handles SVML functions in a different way than general C functions
 [see `test0` and `test1` here](https://godbolt.org/z/av2-b3).

Comment: @Royi: What would be the advantage of writing the whole loop with __m128 pointers? For the performance there should hardly be any difference.

Comment: @wim: oh wow, multiple return values from one function.  Neat that they found a way to work around that crappy limitation of standard C calling conventions by using a custom convention.  I was assuming that the SVML function got a pointer and would actually do the store itself, but this is much better.

Comment: @wim, Well, I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking. I'm not an expert hence didn't know. I have a code with a lot of Element Wise operations yet it seems it is still not efficient. I will post it and link here. Maybe you will have idea how to reduce overhead. Thank You.

Comment: @PeterCordes, any chance having you looking at - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/203356? Thank You.